# my first javascript code not working - home made image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I was given the script found here http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/2/ but cannot get it to seem to work. Can anyone spot why?

The 3 images are meant to display on top in turn, like an image slider.

As I have added a js fiidle link the images will not show, only their alt attributes

Comment: Do you have a specific question about something?

Comment: Because I'm pretty new to jquery and javascript I am not sure what to ask about specifically. What I do know is that my code is not working and I am not sure if it is the html, css or jquery, which is why I added the link to jsfiddle. I wish I could be more specific but I am unsure what would be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't enable jQuery in your jsFiddle. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/b2Nq9/3/